# iterate over a collection and return the matching element

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a AudioFile that has_many photos. A photo has an attribute "primary" (0 or 1 in db) What is an idiomatic ruby way of doing something like this: I want to have a method on the AudioFile which returns the id of the primary photo, i.e the photo that has primary attribute set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the best practice would be to set up a `named_scope` in your `Photo` model.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :primary, :conditions => {:primary => true}
end
```

Then you can call the primary scope on your photos assocations. e.g.

```
@audio_file.photos.primary.first
```

You could also wrap this in a helper method.

```
def primary_photo
  photos.primary.first
end
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html for more details and examples or google named_scope.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but [Enumerable#Select](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003125) will give you all the items out of an enumerable object that match a case (given in a block).

Comment: so I can write

  def primary_photo
    self.photos.select {|element| element.primary = 'true'}
  end